# Insert multiple image using Repeater with mediafinder in OctoberCMS

Tags: repeater, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm creating a new Plugin using the Builder Plugin and adding a repeater with media finder.The problem is to insert repeater value in the database. Bellow have attached the screenshot of the error.

[image]

[image]

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field must be jsonable, so you need to add the following code in your model file.

```
protected $jsonable = [
    'images'
];
```